# Talend tmap lookup on multiple conditions with the same lookup table

Tags: talend

I'm using talend to build out a job but have run into a problem.

I have multiple variables that need to be created that each rely on a lookup of table, `'X'`.

For example,

```
  var_a = tablex.columnA where tablex.columnb == "A"
  var_b = tablex.columnA where tablex.columnc == "B"
```

etc.

Unfortunately it seems that using the lookup functionality in the left pane affects the entire `tmap` function - i.e., you can't restrict to `columnB` for some variables and `columnC` for others.

Is it possible to build `var_a` and `var_b` without having to replicate the lookup table subjob each time? Is there a way to do this using the expression editor?

**EDIT:** I've drafted a few slides with screenshots to more clearly show my problem. Please take a look here: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1OeIGEIpxPXPJtjGAfpAWj83jhCMDSLbSMb3ygZism9Q/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

[image: VarA setting]

[image: VarB setting]

you need to have 1 person file as main and 2 Address file as lookup because according to your data, for country value you need first match of lookup and for gender value you need the match model as last match.

for first lookup, in tMap match ID column and write the expression for country population given below.

For Second lookup, in tMap match ID column and write the expression for gender population given below

Comment: this didn't work. can you point me towards documentation that shows how this is done? The talend user guide doesn't cover this type of lookup.

Comment: for clarification of above, the error i'm getting is "lookup cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: I've added proper screenshots to more clearly state the problem etc. Could you take a look and let me know what to do? Thanks: https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1OeIGEIpxPXPJtjGAfpAWj83jhCMDSLbSMb3ygZism9Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: edited my above comment. please refer the screenshot